# The method parseInt(String) is undefined for the type Integer

Tags: java, string, integer

I need to transform a string to an int using Integer.parseInt() or Integer.valueOf() but Visual Studio Code shows this error *The method parseInt(String) is undefined for the type Integer*

This is my code so far

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class entrada2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nombre_usuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu nombre de usuario, por favor");
        String edad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu edad, por favor");

        int age = Integer.parseInt(edad);

        System.out.println("Te llamas " + nombre_usuario + " y tienes " + edad + " años.");

    }


}
```

I don't know what's the problem. Google hasn't been helpful either

Apparently Integer.parseInt() is the only way to make an integer from a string in Java so I'm stuck

Comment: It sounds like there might be an issue with your Java installation or configuration. Integer.parseInt() is a standard Java method that is part of the java.lang.Integer class, so it should be available by default.

One thing you could try is explicitly importing the java.lang.Integer class at the top of your file, like this:

    import java.lang.Integer;

If you still have this error, you may need to uninstall and reinstall Java, or try using a different IDE.

Comment: Do you have your own class called `Integer` in the same pacakge?